# PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a MySQL database that I am accessing through PHP. I started by developing and refining my PHP code to access that database with prepared SQL statements. I sent POST requests to test the code (through Python) and got back the expected results.

However, I am unable to do so through JQuery's AJAX feature. I feel as if my code may have imperfections, as I have never used the two in conjunction with MySQL before. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

My error is that when I run my code, I receive no output in the JavaScript console or on the page. The only way I know that my submit function is even being called is by the success of the `alert("called")` statement.

HTML and JQuery:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Login form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sub(form){
            alert("called");
            $form =  $(form);
            $input = $form.find("[name='searchword']");

            $.ajax({
                url: "php/searchOld.php",
                dataType: "application/json",
                type: "POST",
                data: "searchword="+$input.val(),
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                      alert(err.Message);
                },
                success: function(){
                    alert("transaction succeeded");
                    var arr = $.map(obj, function(el){
                        return el;
                    });
                    printResults(arr);

                }
            });
        }

        function printResults(arr){
            for(var title of arr){
                $pTag = $("<p></p>");
                $pTag.append("<b>"+title+"</b>");
                $("#titles").append($pTag);
            }
        }

    </script>

    <form id = "searchForm" method="POST" onsubmit = "sub(this)">
        Enter the searchword: <input type="text" name = "searchword"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <br><br>

    <div id = "titles">

    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
   <?php
    include("connect.php");
    $search = "%".$_POST['searchword']."%";



    $query = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT Title FROM `right` WHERE Title LIKE ?");
    if(!$query){
        echo mysqli_error($link);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $search);

    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($title);
    $data = array();
    while($query->fetch()){
        array_push($data, $title);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

Comment: There is jquery ajax code error as well as php script has errors too. First solve the php file. Comment out the `$search = "%".$_POST['searchword']."%";` line and hard code the `$search="something"` then run the php scrip directly and see what is the output. If it shows the json encoded array of titles then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to return false inside function like so :

```
 function sub(form){
   .......
   .......
   return false; // to prevent normal default behavior of form(page refresh) 
 }
```

And inside success block function need to pass parameter that hold result obj from server side respond like so :

```
success: function( obj ){
                    ^------------------ here
   alert("transaction succeeded");
   var arr = $.map(obj, function(el){
               return el;
       });
   printResults(arr);
}
```

Or simply return`onsubmit inline` like so :

```
onsubmit="sub(this);return false;"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added both things, but I still get the same result. I am trying to test AJAX on a text file, and same thing happens

Comment: I'll try that, and for the text file, I was using the wrong function :P. Rookie mistake, sorry

Comment: OK thanks a lot, it worked. Now I have a bunch of JavaScript errors to deal with, but at least I know what to fix

Comment: Glad to hear that, and yeah fix line by line mate. Its fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

**HTML**

```
 <form id = "searchForm" method="POST" onsubmit = "return sub(this)">
     Enter the searchword: <input type="text" name = "searchword"><br>
     <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

**JS**

```
function sub(form) {
    $form =  $(form);
    $input = $form.find("[name='searchword']");

    $.ajax({
        url: "php/searchOld.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: "searchword="+$input.val(),
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(status+'---'+error);
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert("transaction succeeded");
            var arr = $.map(msg, function(el) {
                return el;
            });
            printResults(arr); 

        }
    });
    return false;
}

function printResults(arr) {
    for(var title of arr) {
        $pTag = $("<p></p>");
        $pTag.append("<b>"+title+"</b>");
        $("#titles").append($pTag);
    }
}
```